# Duplicated function

Tags: c#

In my code I make a connection with the Google calendar API. First I authenticate and then I request a list with all the data I need. Now I have a problem, because I need to request in three different ways. See below:

```
PrivateExtendedProperty = new string[] { "UserId=" + userId },

PrivateExtendedProperty = new string[] { "ClassroomId=" + classroomId },  

PrivateExtendedProperty = new string[] { "ClassroomId=" + classroomId , "UserId=" + userId },
```

I use these in the function below. But I don't want to copy this function three times and only change the parameters and the private properties. What is the best way to refactor this and solve the duplication problem.

The whole function:

```
public List<Meeting> GetMeetings(DateTime minTime, DateTime maxTime, string userId, int classroomId)
{
    CalendarService service = AuthenticateAccount(CalendarId);

    EventsResource.ListRequest request = new EventsResource.ListRequest(service, CalendarId)
    {
        TimeMin = timeMin,
        TimeMax = timeMax,
        TimeZone = "Europe/Amsterdam",
        PrivateExtendedProperty = new string[] { "ClassroomId=" + classroomId , "UserId=" + userId },             
    };

    Events events = request.Execute();

    foreach (var item in eventList)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the two id parameters and add a `string[]` parameter, so: `GetMeetings(DateTime minTime, DateTime maxTime, string[] privateExtendedProperty)`

Comment: Simplest way is to Use UserID in the constructor and then remove UserID from all other calls.  So you only use the second method with only ClassroomId.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With that many parameters, this is becoming a code smell.

Refactor the parameters into their own class (SRP - Single Responsibility Principle)

```
public class MeetingOptions {
    public DateTime minTime { get; set; } 
    public DateTime maxTime { get; set; } 
    public string userId { get; set; } 
    public int? classroomId { get; set; } 
}
```

The building of the extended property can be extracted out into it's own method/concern as well

```
string[] buildExtendedProperty(MeetingOptions options) {
    var extendedProperty = new List<String>();

    if (options.userId != null)
        extendedProperty.Add("UserId=" + options.userId);

    if (options.classroomId.HasValue)
        extendedProperty.Add("classroomId=" + options.classroomId);

    return extendedProperty.ToArray();
}
```

Note: *there is potential here to refactor that out into it's own service as well but that is outside of the scope of the current question.*

Refactor the method to use the new class as the parameter (Explicit dependency principle)

```
public List<Meeting> GetMeetings(MeetingOptions options) {
    CalendarService service = AuthenticateAccount(CalendarId);

    string[] extendedProperty = buildExtendedProperty(options);

    EventsResource.ListRequest request = new EventsResource.ListRequest(service, CalendarId) {
        TimeMin = options.timeMin,
        TimeMax = options.timeMax,
        TimeZone = "Europe/Amsterdam",
        PrivateExtendedProperty = extendedProperty,
    };

    Events events = request.Execute();

    foreach (var item in eventList) {
        //....
    }
}
```

The function can then be called with the necessary properties populated to follow a DRY principle.

Comment: Thank you very much for your well explained answer!

Answer (score 3):

Just make `classroomId` nullable, and add some logic so the request is sent with only the parameters the caller provided.

```
public List<Meeting> GetMeetings(DateTime minTime, DateTime maxTime, 
                                 string userId = null, int? classroomId = null)
{
    CalendarService service = AuthenticateAccount(CalendarId);

    var extProp = new List<String>();

    if (userId != null) {
        extProp.Add("UserId=" + userId);
    }
    if (classroomId.HasValue) {
        extProp.Add("classroomId=" + classroomId);
    }

    //  Optional: Throw exception if extProp is empty

    EventsResource.ListRequest request = new EventsResource.ListRequest(service, CalendarId)
    {
        TimeMin = timeMin,
        TimeMax = timeMax,
        TimeZone = "Europe/Amsterdam",
        PrivateExtendedProperty = extProp.ToArray()
    };
```

I would use Nkosi's approach if I expected to add new parameters over time, or if I wanted to maintain a list of "favorite" or "recent" searches. I'd do something semi-clever with a base class that would create have TimeMin, TimeMax etc., and would create `ListRequest` instances with appropriate `PrivateExtendedProperty` values.

Answer (score 0):

You should use optional parameters in the function declaration and dynamically generate a string array to be sent in "PrivateExtendedProperty".

Take a look at [C# Optional Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments) docs for reference.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says

https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Calendar_1_1v3_1_1EventsResource_1_1ListRequest.html#a2d1fe67042944d5f7bd0cf2d3bcaac88

> "This parameter might be repeated multiple times to return events that
>   match all given constraints"

Just repeat three times in the same function.... It is type of `Google.Apis.Util.Repeatable`